# Polite way to say "I am fine" in spanish

Tags: gramática, verbos

When My boss asks "Como estas? I reply :
"Estoy muy muy  feliz" Does it make sense in spanish? Or What is a better/polite way to say "I am fine"?

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense. Maybe too much emphasized but it is ok (it sounds like you are incredibly happy). If you want to mean that you're just ok or fine you could just say "Estoy bien, gracias" or "Muy contento/a" if you're indeed happy but not exageratedly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expression:

> Estoy muy, muy feliz

is fine if you are talking with a close friend and want to share your great vital situation.

But if you want to share something more polite in a random conversation with somebody not being that close, you better use other expressions such as:

> [Muy] bien, gracias.
>
> Estoy bien, gracias.

Note that these kind of questions are normally meant to be used as a salutation, normally people don't expect but a polite reply asking for them. So you normally add a `¿Y tú/usted?` after it.

Funny addendum: In Argentina you can also hear a response like: [`escoge: ¿bien o te cuento?`](http://www.ciudadredonda.org/articulo/bien-o-te-cuento), meaning: I am saying I am fine based on the fact you are just asking this for courtesy; but if you really care, I can tell you :)

Comment: This reminds me of something I read a while ago: *un maleducado es aquel a quien preguntas cómo está y te lo dice*.

Answer (score 1):

"Estoy muy muy feliz" does make sense. But I don't think that is the answer you want to tell to your boss. 
I am going to be concise with this answer: Think about when someone asks you "How are you?" you rarely say "I'am happy." People usually reply "I'm fine, thank you" or "I am good/great"

If you reply "Estoy muy feliz" is not wrong. It depends on the context.